# Filter-closed vs. chain-closed

Tags: order-theory, lattices

Let A is a complete lattice.

I call a subset $S$ of A *filter-closed* when for every filter base $T$ in $S$ we have $\bigcap T\in S$. (A *filter base* is a nonempty, down directed set.)

I call a subset $S$ of A *chain-closed* when for every non-empty chain $T$ in $S$ we have $\bigcap T\in S$.

**Conjecture** $S$ is filter-closed if and only if $S$ is chain-closed.

Comment: Would you mind defining "chain" for completeness sake? I am guessing it is
just a decreasing sequence, but it would be nice to nail this down before
I think too hard about it.

Comment: The formulation of filter-closed is presumably wrong, one instance of A should be S

Comment: A chain is subset of a poset on which the induced order is complete.

Comment: A chain is a totally-ordered set.


Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, your conjecture is correct.

**Theorem.** If L is a complete lattice and S is a subset of L, then S is chain-closed iff S is filter-closed.

Proof. Clearly filter-closed implies chain-closed, since every chain is a filter base. Conversely, suppose that S is chain-closed, and that A is a filter base contained in S. Note that S is trivially filter-closed with respect to any finite filter base. So suppose by induction that S is filter-closed with respect to any filter base of size smaller than |A|. Enumerate A = { a<sub>α</sub> | α < |A| }. Let b<sub>β</sub> be the meet of { a<sub>α</sub> | α < β }. This is the same as the meet of the filter sub-base of A generated by this set. This filter sub-base has size less than |A|, and hence by induction every b<sub>β</sub> is in S. Also, the b<sub>β</sub> are a descending chain in S, since as we take more a<sub>α</sub>, the meet gets smaller. Thus, by the chain-closure of S, the meet b of all the b<sub>β</sub> is in S. This meet b is the same as the meet of A, and so we have proved that S is filter-closed. QED

This argument is very similar to the following characterization of (downward) complete lattices (which I had posted as my original answer).

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent, for any
lattice L.

- L is complete, in the sense that every subset of L has a
  greatest lower bound.
- L is filter complete, meaning that every filter base in
  L has a greatest lower bound.
- L is chain complete, meaning that every filter base in L
  has a greatest lower bound.

Proof. It is clear that completeness implies filter
completeness, since every filter base is a subset of L, and
filter completeness implies chain completeness, since every
chain is a filter base. For the remaining implication, suppose that L is chain
complete. We want to show that every subset A of L has a
greatest lower bound in L. We can prove this by transfinite
induction on the size of A. Clearly this is true for any
finite set, since L is a lattice. Fix any infinite set A.
Enumerate A as { a<sub>α</sub> | α < |A| }.
By the induction hypothesis, for each β < |A|, the
set { a<sub>α</sub> | α < β } has a
greatest lower bound b<sub>β</sub>. Note that {
b<sub>β</sub> | β < |A| } is a chain, because
as we include more elements into the sets, the greatest
lower bound becomes smaller. Thus, there is an element b in
L that is the greatest lower bound of the
b<sub>β</sub>'s. It is easy to see that this element b
is also a lower bound of A. QED

One can describe the method as finding a linearly ordered
cofinal sequence through the filter generated by the filter
base. This proof used AC when A was enumerated, and I
believe that this cannot be omitted.

One can modify the argument to show that for every infinite
cardinal κ, then a lattice is κ-complete (every
subset of size less than κ has a glb) iff every
filter base of size less than κ has a glb iff every
chain of size less than κ has a glb.

Note that if the lattice is *bounded* (meaning that it has
a least and greatest element), then having greatest lower
bounds for every set is the same as having least upper
bounds for every set, since the least upper bound of a set
A is the greatest lower bound of the set of upper bounds of
A. Thus, a *complete lattice* is often defined as saying
that every subset has a glb and lub.

There have been a few questions here at MO concerning
complete lattices. See [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11728) and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11435).

Questions about the degree of completeness of a partial
order often arise in connection with forcing arguments, and
when one is speaking of partial completeness and partial
orders (rather than lattices), and the situation is
somewhat more subtle. For example, a partial order P is
said to be κ-closed if every linearly ordered subset
of P of size less than κ has a lower bound. It is
κ-directed closed if every filter base in P of size
less than κ has a lower bound. With these concepts,
it is no longer true that a partial order is
κ-directed closed if and only if it is
κ-closed. One example arising in forcing would be the
forcing to add a slim κ-Kurepa tree, which is
κ-closed but not κ-directed closed. The
difference between these two concepts is related to
questions of large cardinal indestructibility, for Richard
Laver proved that every supercompact cardinal κ can
become indestructible by all κ-directed closed
forcing, but no such cardinal can ever be indestructible by
all κ-closed forcing, precisely because the slim
κ-Kurepa tree forcing destroys the measurability of
κ.

Comment: This is correct but there is a subtlety with the question. It is not sufficient to show that S is by itself a complete lattice, you also need that the meets of filters in S are the same as those computed in the enveloping complete lattice A. A small variation of your argument does this.

Comment: Francois, you are right. I was mainly thinking just about whether completeness is equivalently characterized by filters and chains for a lattice.  But the same idea works, and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note: It isn't generally true that S will be a complete lattice, for it needn't even be a lattice. For example, perhaps S is an antichain in the larger lattice. This is trivially chain-closed, since all chains in S have only one element. (And it is also trivially filter-closed, since all filter bases subset S also have only one element.) 

Comment: "This filter sub-base has size less than |A|" - why?

Comment: Can we add an additional equivalent statement to the formulation of the conjecture we have proved? (such as: the meet of T is in S for every non-empty subset T of S)

Comment: Oh, well, I understood why "This filter sub-base has size less than |A|". The cardinality of generated filter base cannot be greater than cardinality of natural numbers multiplied with the cardinality of the set which generates the filter base. Because it is infinite we have the same cardinality of the generated set as of the generating set.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea for calculating the cardinality of the filter base. And no, you cannot add set-completeness as an equivalent condition about S, since S may not be a lattice. It may not even have meets and joins for its finite subsets (although these will exist in the ambient lattice L, but not in the subset S). For example, if S is an antichain in L with at least two elements, then S is chain-closed and filter-closed, but not set-complete, since no two distinct elements of S have a meet or join.

Comment: "This meet b is the same as the meet of A" - why?

Comment: It is a lower bound of A, since it is below every b_beta, and hence below every a_alpha. If x is below every element of A, then x is below every a_alpha, and hence below every b_beta, and hence below x.

Comment: To prove that that being below every b_beta implies being below every a_alpha, you seem to suppose that there exists beta such that alpha<beta<|A| for every alpha<|A|. What this follows from? Or I misunderstand?

Comment: That follows from the fact that |A| is an infinite cardinal, and hence a limit ordinal. (The case of finite A is free.)

Comment: Thus your proof uses ordinal numbers not cardinal numbers as I'd expect. This is great but a little unnatural. Maybe this proof may be reformulated with cardinal numbers only (without using arbitrary ordinals)? (just curious now, any proof is OK for me writing an article containing this theorem)

Comment: One more question: How to write the proof with ordinals? I can't say Ord is a set of all ordinals because Ord is not a set.

{ a_α | α < |A| } is not formally correct because it is not stated here that α are ordinals. { a_α | α in Ord and α < |A| } is not formally correct in ZFC because Ord is not a set.

How to write this?

Comment: Why cardinality of beta is less than |A|? (for every beta in |A|) This is needed for justification of the assumption of induction.

Comment: Oh, I found the positive answer on my last question follows from Von Neumann cardinal assignment.

Comment: In set theory, the relation < on (Von Neumann) ordinals is the same as epsilon (that is, set membership). So writing { a_alpha | alpha < |A| } is perfectly acceptable. But to reinforce the ordinal interpretation, you should also refer to alpha as an ordinal in the argument. 

Answer (score 4):

How is the following related to the question...

Let $P$ be a partially-ordered set.  Suppose every chain in $P$ has a least upper bound.  Then every subset of $P$ which is directed has a least upper bound.

I needed this once, long ago, didn't find it, so included a proof in the paper.  Many years later someone gave me a reference for it:  Mayer-Kalkschmidt & Steiner, *Duke Math. J.* 31 (1964) 287-289

Comment: No, your answer is on a different problem than I asked.

Comment: @Porton: It's not that different. Your chain-closed subset S is a poset where each chain has a greatest lower bound. By the (dual of the ) above, every filter in S has a greatest lower bound in S. All you need to check is if this greatest lower bound is indeed the same as the one in A. You will figure that out pretty quickly by looking at the proof...

Answer (score 0):

I made a post to sci.math regarding this question.  You might check that post for some suggestions.  Others might check the thread for more history on that problem.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.02.18

Comment: I don't see your post in sci.math!
Note also that I already have asked this in sci.math a few months ago.

Comment: A Google Groups search on "Paseman filter" brings it up quickly.  The advice there was (essentially) to study the finite case.

Comment: The reason it is hard to find... The "From" line is not "Gerhard Paseman" but "Ask me about System Design".  Dated December 30, 2009.


Answer (score 0):

I wrote more detailed proof based on the proof by Joel David Hamkins in [this online article](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/filters.pdf).