# a characterization for cyclic groups

Tags: finite-groups, lattice-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $n$ and its subgroup lattice be order-isomorphic to that of $\Bbb Z_n$. Is $G$ cyclic‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Comment: Answered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35455/does-subgroup-structure-of-a-finite-group-characterize-isomorphism-type (see Tony Hyunh's answer).

Comment: **Ore's theorem**: a group is [locally cyclic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_group) iff its subgroups lattice is distributive. See a proof [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/179555/34538).

Comment: this question is somewhat old. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, finite cyclic groups are exactly the finite groups whose lattices of subgroups are distributive. The lattice of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is isomorphic to the dual of a divisibility lattice (which is distributive).

Comment: btw, it seems to be the divisibility lattice itself and not its dual.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: The divisibility lattice is self-dual.