# Reconstruction conjecture and partial 2-trees

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-reconstruction

[Reconstruction conjecture](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/reconstruction_conjecture) says that graphs (with at least three vertices) are determined uniquely by their vertex deleted subgraphs. This conjecture is five decades old.

Searching relevant literature, I found that the following classes of graphs are known to be reconstructible :

- trees
- disconnected graphs, graphs whose complement is disconnected
- regular graphs
- Maximal Outerplanar Graphs
- maximal planar graphs
- outerplanar graphs
- Critical blocks
- Separable graphs without end vertices
- unicyclic graphs (graphs with one cycle)
- non-trivial cartesian product graphs
- squares of trees
- bidegreed graphs
- unit interval graphs
- threshold graphs
- nearly acyclic graphs (i.e., G-v is acyclic)
- cacti graphs
- graphs for which one of the vertex deleted graph is a forest.

I recently proved that a special case of partial 2-trees are reconstructible. I am wondering if partial 2-trees (a.k.a [series-parallel graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph)) are known to be reconstructible. Partial 2-trees do not seem to fall into any of the above mentioned categories.

- Am I missing any other known classes of reconstructible graphs in the above list ?
- In particular, are partial 2-trees known to be reconstructible ?

I asked this [question at cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/reconstruction-conjecture-and-partial-2-trees) website also.

Comment: Very nice question, I would assume someone has studied relations between reconstruction and treewidth.

Comment: @Shiva, can you please tell me which of the proofs used algebraic graph theory? The  answer  may come here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34914/reconstruction-conjecture-group-theoretic-formulation

Comment: If you gave me a good definition of 2-tree in the post, and a couple not-so-obvious reasons why it doesn't seem to fit in some of the classes on the list, I might be inclined to answer (or at least think about) your question.  I am not yet inspired to look up the definition myself and check.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: Yes, I see the link to series-parallel graphs, but I still prefer a recap of "partial 2-tree".  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: $K_2$ is a 2-tree. If $X$ is a 2-tree then so is $X + v$ where $v$ lies in a triangle with 2 vertices of $X$. There are no other 2-trees. A partial 2-tree is a 2-tree with some edges removed.