# Is there a conjunction bias?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, lo.logic

This is slightly related to question [The unprecedented success of the “intersection” operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33366/the-unprecedented-success-of-the-intersection-operator) .

Apart from a set of maths books of null measure, most have the following property:

**Objects definitions are presented as a conjunction of properties.**

Most axiomatic are also clearly conjunctive in their presentation.
It is uncommon to have say "*By definition a Zorglub is a red zorg **or** a white zorg*".

**Q1** : Do you agree with the bias (if not, give enough examples)?.

**Q2**:  Is this bias mainly a discourse convention or does it lie deeper (where?) ?

Comment: We generally want to talk about very specific things; conjunctions increase specificity, and hence they're useful. Maybe I'm missing the point---are you asking for more than this sort of answer?

Comment: Conjunctivitis can be extremely contagious.

Comment: @Scott: Specificity is relative (level) . A 'human being' is a man of a woman ( Yet of course you could argue that the right name is 'social human being' and that is certainly less natural as a concept as it's longer name shows).Yes I ask for more but your idea is good as one of the reason for the bias, yet it look to me as not being the only one.  

Comment: I don't think I agree with this bias- every time we say "by abuse of notation" we mean a disjunction. A common disjunction in mathematics would be define a zorg to be either a specific zorg or an equivalence class of zorgs, and similarly for maps between zorgs. For instance, a knot is a PL embedding of S^1 in S^3 or in R^3; or an ambient isotopy class thereof.

Comment: When I first saw this question, my impression was that it was too broad to get useful answers.  But I wasn't sure, so I let it lie for a while to see what kind of answers would be given.  Now, 14 hours later, the response I like best is Tom Goodwillie's conjunctivitis joke...so I have voted to close.

Comment: I'm with Pete.${}$

Comment: @Pete: before closing tell me : do you think this is obviously always true,(my position more or less)  or else give me a fair share of examples where the bias is false. 

Comment: @Moskovich: 1) For the case of a 'specific zorg' , I believe this is a conjunction ( Def: Is a zorg AND has a specificity). 
2) For the equivalence class I agree and think it is a very nice (broad) class of counter examples. 
3) For the maps I don't agree : 'a map of zorgs is a map that is MOREOVER zorgish ( respect the structure)' . This 'moreover' sounds pretty conjunctive to me? 
4) What is a PL , this example looks is very nice and semantic semantic it seems to belong to the 'equivalence' type of 2. 
Altogether it seems that the OR appears when we are doing some identification ? 


Comment: A global field is either a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ or a finite extension of $\mathbb F_p(t)$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: @Tom: Ok your 'OR' is about two different objects. Yet I don't know about the Emil Artin but it looks as if things ended with your definition (did not start with it). So this would be a nice case of naming a conclusion (see answer below). In other words your fact says a global field COMES under two different guises, it does not says a global field IS this or that.    

Answer (score 12):

A slightly tongue-in-cheek answer: definitions are the hypotheses of theorems.  If the hypothesis of a theorem is a disjunction, you can always split the theorem up into two theorems with separate hypotheses, and doing so will often clarify the statement and proof anyway.  So it's natural that single definitions are not usually disjunctive.

(Dually, if the conclusion of a theorem is a conjunction, then you can split it up into two theorems with separate conclusions.  But I think we don't as often give names to the conclusions of theorems, unless they happen to coincide with a definition we gave for some other reason elsewhere.)

Comment: @Mike : OK very nice point! It covers definitions that are tailor maid for a theorem (to clarify exposition) and this does not preclude them to be meaningful, There also the case of specialization that fit the conjunction bias yet does not seem to enter your case ? Do you agree? 

Comment: "Specialization" meaning what?

Comment: I was not precise : A green zorg is a specialization of a zorg, and this fit the bill, this was my idea. A vector space on the reals can also clearly be called a specialization (of vector space), it fit the bill of conjunction  (may be not so well): One says V IS a vector space on a field F AND F = R.  
I use specialization as adding/picking 1 or more specifics. 

Comment: But why do we specialize a definition in some way?  Often, because there is some theorem we can prove in the specialized case but don't (yet) know how to prove in the general case.  I didn't just mean definitions tailored for particular theorems; more generally we tend to make definitions so that we can then prove numerous theorems using those definitions as hypotheses.

Comment: Ok agreed. You sometimes may also specialize a true general result to illustrate (obtain mental pictures). I think I use specialization in the sense of particularization. 
